# Buscar uma determinada linha ou valor específico de um vetor em matriz no R

Tags: r, matriz, condição

Como construir uma função que avalie se uma linha qualquer da matriz `mat` é igual ao vetor `vec` ambos no código abaixo:

```
set.seed(000)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(20),4,5)
vec <- c(1.3297993, -0.9285670,  0.7635935, -0.2992151,  0.4356833)
mat[3,]
vec
mat==vec
```

Além disso, como determinar se pelo menos um valor de `vec` está em `mat`?

Obs: Entendo que `mat==vec` deve ser igual `TRUE`, ou seja, `mat-vec==0` se `mat-vec<tol`, onde `tol = 1e-5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `all.equal` dá o resultado que tu deseja. Eu não utilizei o `mat` do teu exemplo porque meu computador, mesmo com a semente ajustada, gera números aleatórios diferentes do teu. Por isso, criei uma nova matriz com valores bem determinados.

```
mat  <- matrix(1:50, ncol=5)
vec1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
vec2 <- c(1, 11, 21, 31, 41)
vec3 <- c(5, 15, 25, 35, 45)

which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) all.equal(x, vec1)) == "TRUE")
integer(0)
which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) all.equal(x, vec2)) == "TRUE")
[1] 1
which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) all.equal(x, vec3)) == "TRUE")
[1] 5
```

O que a função `all.equal` faz é comparar dois objetos no `R` para ver se eles são razoavelmente iguais. O bom desta função é que ela tem um argumento chamado `tolerance` (que eu utilizo abaixo) para resolver justamente o problema de tolerância que pode aparecer nas tuas simulações.

Utilizando o `apply`, eu consigo aplicar a função `all.equal` a todas as linhas da matriz, sem necessitar de um loop.

Segue abaixo uma sugestão de função para reproduzir este resultado:

```
linha <- function(matriz, vetor){
  aux <- which(apply(matriz, 1, function(matriz) all.equal(matriz, vetor, tolerance=1e-5)) == "TRUE")

  if (length(aux) > 0){
    resposta <- aux
  } else {
    resposta <- "nao existe"
  }

  return(resposta)
}

linha(mat, vec1)
[1] "nao existe"
linha(mat, vec2)
[1] 1
linha(mat, vec3)
[1] 5
```

Para descobrir se ao menos um elemento do vetor está na matriz, utilize um código similar a este acima, mas sem a função `all.equal`:

```
which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x == vec1))
[1] 1
which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x == vec2))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) x == vec3))
[1] 21 22 23 24 25
```

Assim tu vai saber exatamente quais as posições de `mat` que possuem elementos de `vec`.

Answer (score 1):

Coma função abaixo você pode comparar ou as linhas ou colunas de uma matriz com um vetor, respeitado um nível de tolerância numérica. Se `fun = all` você compara todos os elementos do vetor. Se `fun = any` você verifica se ao menos um elemento do vetor é igual (respeitada a ordem):

```
search_vec <- function(mat, vec, dim = 1, tol = 1e-7, fun = all)
  which(apply(mat, dim, function(x) fun(abs(x - vec) < tol)))
```

Aplicando ao seu caso, procuramos o vetor `vec` nas linhas da matriz `mat`, comparando todos elementos. A função retorna linha 3 como resposta:

```
search_vec(mat, vec)
[1] 3
```

Um outro caso, suponha que alteremos o primeiro valor de `vec`. Se você buscar por todos os elementos iguais a resposta será vazia.

```
vec[1] <- 10
search_vec(mat, vec)
integer(0)
```

Mas se você pedir `fun = any`, a função verifica se ao menos um elemento é igual, e a resposta será linha 3:

```
search_vec(mat, vec, fun = any)
[1] 3
```

Outra situação, suponha que queiramos saber que linha contém  `-0.799009249`. Nesse caso você também pode usar `fun = any` e a resposta é linha 4:

```
search_vec(mat, -0.799009249, fun = any)
[1] 4
```

Se você quiser buscar colunas, mude para `dim = 2`.